# Shortcut to open Terminal isn't working in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, lxterminal

I have a problem. I tried to change my default terminal on Lubuntu but I changed it back. The problem is that I can't use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open lxterminal. Actually does nothing, even if I change the hotkey. Other hotkeys are working though

PS: Sorry about the title, I created and didn't pay attention to it.

Comment: *"I tried to change my default terminal on Lubuntu but I changed it back"* How, and how?

Comment: the default is lxterminal and I changed on the standard apps ui. it didn`t work so i changed it back. Since then this shortcut doesn`t work.